# How to fill a footable from a json

Tags: javascript, html, json, footable

I have my html code like this defining a footable

```
              <table class="table toggle-circle" id="exampleRowToggler">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th data-field="marca">Marca</th>
                        <th data-field="modelo">Modelo</th>
                        <th data-field="placa">Placa</th>
                        <th data-field="chasis">Chasis</th>
                        <th data-field="vigencia_desde">Vigencia Desde</th>
                        <th data-field="vigencia_hasta">Vigendia Hasta</th>
                    <th data-hide="all">Clausulas</th>
                    <th data-hide="all">Exclusiones</th>
                    <th data-hide="all">Beneficios</th>
                    <th data-hide="all">Deducibles</th>
                    <th data-hide="all">Coberturas</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                </tbody>
              </table>
```

and I want to fill it from a .js file that contains a function with the data in json like this. I've tried some options but still can't get it and the last thing I've tried was this.

```
loadTable: function () {

            var bt_data = [{
                    "marca": "HYUNDAI",
                    "modelo": "IONIQ",
                    "placa": "T02096577",
                    "chasis":"KMHC851CGHU029520",
                    "vigencia_desde":"22/05/2017",
                    "vigencia_hasta":"22/05/2018",
                    "clausulas": "clauuuuuusulaaas",
                    "exclusiones": "eeexclusioooonesss",
                    "beneficios": "beeeeneeefiiiciiiooosss",
                    "deducibles":"deeeeduuuuciiiibleeeessss",
                    "coberturas":"cooooobeeeertuuuuraaaasssss"
                }];

                    $('#exampleRowToggler').footable({
                        "useParentWidth": true,
                        "columns": $.get('columns.bt_data'),
                        "rows": $.get('rows.bt_data')
                    });
        }
```

help me please.

Comment: "I want to fill it from a .js file that contains a function with the data in json" In that case you'd have to include the JS file in the page, and then call the function. But what you're actually doing is making an ajax request to an endpoint. That would be expected to provide the actual data in raw JSON format, not a JavaScript function.

Answer (score 1):

The columns and rows values that you are passing in to footable will be producing nothing at all unless you have a server side page listening for the "columns.bt_data" and "rows.bt_data" URLs and returning relevant JSON/array responses.

Here's what I think you wanted to do:

```
loadTable: function () {
    var bt_data = [{
        "marca": "HYUNDAI",
        "modelo": "IONIQ",
        "placa": "T02096577",
        "chasis":"KMHC851CGHU029520",
        "vigencia_desde":"22/05/2017",
        "vigencia_hasta":"22/05/2018",
        "clausulas": "clauuuuuusulaaas",
        "exclusiones": "eeexclusioooonesss",
        "beneficios": "beeeeneeefiiiciiiooosss",
        "deducibles":"deeeeduuuuciiiibleeeessss",
        "coberturas":"cooooobeeeertuuuuraaaasssss"
    }];

    //get Column JSON from first item in Rows array
    var columnJSON = $.map(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(bt_data[0]), function (column) {
        return {"name": column,"title": column}
    });

    $('#exampleRowToggler').footable({
        "useParentWidth": true,
        "columns": columnJSON, //Pass columns object through to footable
        "rows": bt_data //Pass your existing rows array through to footable
    });
}
```